# Helm template command gives me what i want, but when deploying the chart on argo the ConfigMap data is empty

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argocd

I have a helm chart that I am using for multiple deployments.
In the chart  I have a values folder. and in that folder I have subfolders for each deployment and environment, and there I have my values files and also data for the configMaps associated with the deployment.
my chart knows how to extract the data from there, and build it into the ConfigMap.
when running helm template with the values file I want, I get exactly what I want.
but when deploying the app on argoCD, the data attribute in the configMap is empty.
the weird thing is, that in some of the deployments I do get the outcome I want, and in some, I don't.

there's really no code to show, more like understanding how comes when helm template works, the argo deployment does not.

Comment: Without a git repo to show the files, it will be hard to debug... 1 thing that come to my mind: check that the Application is using all the values you want (helm.valuesFiles)

Comment: So i figured it out. The folders that contained the values were lowercase, as they should. That's why helm template worked like a charm. But in the git the folder names were uppercase in some of the cases so through argo it didn't work.

Comment: nice, good to know!